# Simple Console Snake Game

Tags: c++, object-oriented, snake-game

I have created a Snake console game using object-orientated programming methods. This is the first time I have ever used OOP so I just wanted to know if I was using the method correctly as well as hear any other advise I could possibly receive as this is my first time doing this. There are 4 header files and 4 .cpp files used.

Direction.h:

```
#pragma once
enum class Direction {
    STOP = 0, UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
};
```

Food.h:

```
#pragma once
class Food{
private:
    int foodX;
    int foodY;
public:
    Food(int x, int y);
    Food();
    int posX() { return foodX; };
    int posY() { return foodY; };
    void Refresh(int x, int y);
};
```

Food.cpp

```
#include "Food.h"

Food::Food(int x, int y)
{
    foodX = x;
    foodY = y;
}

Food::Food()
    :foodX{ 2 }, foodY{ 2 }
{
}

void Food::Refresh(int x, int y)
{
    foodX = x;
    foodY = y;
}
```

Snake.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Direction.h"

class Snake{
private:
    int headX;
    int headY;
    int length;
    Direction dir;
public:
    Snake(int x, int y);
    Snake();
    int posX() { return headX; };
    int posY() { return headY; };
    int len() { return length; };
    void Update();
    void Eat();
    void Change_Dir(Direction direction);
};
```

Snake.cpp

```
#include "Snake.h"

Snake::Snake()
    : headX{ 1 }, headY{ 1 }, length{ 1 }, dir{ Direction::STOP }
{
}

Snake::Snake(int x, int y)
    : length{ 1 }, dir{ Direction::STOP }
{
    headX = x;
    headY = y;
}

void Snake::Update()
{
    switch (dir) {
    case(Direction::LEFT):
        headX--;
        break;
    case(Direction::RIGHT):
        headX++;
        break;
    case(Direction::UP):
        headY--;
        break;
    case(Direction::DOWN):
        headY++;
        break;
    case(Direction::STOP):
        break;
    }

}

void Snake::Eat()
{
    length++;
}

void Snake::Change_Dir(Direction direction)
{
    dir = direction;
}
```

Game.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Snake.h"
#include "Food.h"
#include <vector>

class Game {
private:
    Snake snake;
    Food food;
    int board_height;
    int board_width;
    std::vector<int> Snake_Tail_X;
    std::vector<int> Snake_Tail_Y;
    void Snake_Tail_Update();
    void Board_Colission();
    void Snake_Colission();
    void Eaten();
    void Input_Check();
    void Draw();
    void Logic();
    bool Game_Over;
public:
    Game();
    bool Game_State() { return Game_Over; };
    void Play();
};
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

Game::Game()
    :snake{ 2, 5 }, food{ 5, 5 }, board_height{ 20 }, board_width{ 20 }, Game_Over{ false }, Snake_Tail_X{}, Snake_Tail_Y{}
{
}

void Game::Play()
{
    Draw();
    Logic();
}

void Game::Draw()
{
    int i{ 0 }, j{ 0 }, k{ 0 };

    system("cls");

    for (i = 0; i < board_height; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j < board_width; j++) {

            if (j == snake.posX() && i == snake.posY())
                std::cout << "O";
            else if (j == food.posX() && i == food.posY())
                std::cout << "F";
            else if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == board_height - 1 || j == board_width - 1)
                std::cout << "#";
            else{
                bool tail = false;

                for (k = 0; k < snake.len() - 1; k++) {
                    if (Snake_Tail_X[k] == j && Snake_Tail_Y[k] == i) {
                        std::cout << "o";
                        tail = true;
                    }   
                }

                if(tail == false)
                    std::cout << " ";
            }




        }

        std::cout << std::endl;

    }
    std::cout <<  "Score: " << snake.len()-1;
}

void Game::Logic() 
{
    Input_Check();
    Snake_Tail_Update();
    snake.Update();
    Board_Colission();
    Snake_Colission();
    Eaten();
}

void Game::Snake_Tail_Update()
{
    if (!Snake_Tail_X.empty()) {

        int i{ 0 }, tempX{ 0 }, tempY{ 0 }, temp2X{ 0 }, temp2Y{ 0 };
        tempX = Snake_Tail_X[0];
        tempY = Snake_Tail_Y[0];
        Snake_Tail_X[0] = snake.posX();
        Snake_Tail_Y[0] = snake.posY();

        for (i = 1; i < snake.len()-1; i++) {

            temp2X = Snake_Tail_X[i];
            temp2Y = Snake_Tail_Y[i];

            Snake_Tail_X[i] = tempX;
            Snake_Tail_Y[i] = tempY;

            tempX = temp2X;
            tempY = temp2Y;

        }

    }
}

void Game::Board_Colission(){

    if (snake.posX() == 0 || snake.posX() == board_width-1 || snake.posY() == 0 || snake.posY() == board_height-1) {
        Game_Over = true;
    }
}

void Game::Snake_Colission()
{
    int i{ 0 };

    for (i = 0; i < snake.len() - 1; i++) {
        if (snake.posX() == Snake_Tail_X[i] && snake.posY() == Snake_Tail_Y[i])
            Game_Over = true;
    }

}

void Game::Eaten()
{
    if (snake.posX() == food.posX() && snake.posY() == food.posY()) {
        food.Refresh(rand() % (board_width - 2) + 1, rand() % (board_height - 2) + 1);
        snake.Eat();
        Snake_Tail_X.push_back(1);
        Snake_Tail_Y.push_back(1);
    }
}

void Game::Input_Check(){
    if (_kbhit()) {

        switch(_getch()){
        case('a'):
            snake.Change_Dir(Direction::LEFT);
            break;
        case('d'):
            snake.Change_Dir(Direction::RIGHT);
            break;
        case('w'):
            snake.Change_Dir(Direction::UP);
            break;
        case('s'):
            snake.Change_Dir(Direction::DOWN);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Main.cpp

````
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"

int main()
{
    Game game;

    while (!game.Game_State()) {
        game.Play();

    }

    return 0;

} 
```
````

Comment: Just wondering, did you write this on Linux?

Comment: Hi pacmaninbw, I wrote this on Windows in Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 4):

### Const methods

These:

```
    int posX() { return foodX; };
    int posY() { return foodY; };
// ...
    int posX() { return headX; };
    int posY() { return headY; };
    int len() { return length; };
```

don't modify anything in `this`, so make them `const`:

```
    int posX() const { return foodX; };
    int posY() const { return foodY; };
```

### Setters

This:

```
void Refresh(int x, int y);
```

is unusual. You're forcing the user to update both `x` and `y` at the same time. In a different universe where you care about atomic interactions in a multithreaded application, this might matter, but here it doesn't. Effectively since you have unlimited read/write ability to this class, it's not even worth making individual setter methods - just boil this down to a `struct` with two public member variables and be done with it.

### Nomenclature

```
    bool Game_Over;
```

is styled to look like a method but it should actually match the capitalization of your other member variables (i.e. lowercase).

`Game_State` would make sense as a name if you were returning an `enum`, but since you aren't: it should probably be called something like `isGameOver()`.

### Characters instead of strings

This

```
std::cout << "O";
```

should be

```
std::cout << 'O';
```

### Unused includes

Remove

```
#include <iostream>
```

from your `main.cpp`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the feedback, I really appreciate it.